# NetBeans 8.2 create not project

Tags: java, netbeans

I am sure it is simple problem, but I am new to Java and PHP, I want to learn Java, I bought a book, I have also a couple of books as PDF from internet, at the Beginning of the book there is always intructions, how you can install for example NetBeans to start programming. I have installed jdk 8 and NetBeans 8.2.

The problem is, when I start NetBeans, the Buttons for creating new Project not function and is not reacting on my click. I have installed all plugins. I have searched the internet. I have found, that I should click create new Project, I will get a dialogue, then I should choose the desired project. But it shows nothing when I click that button, it simply does not react. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: does `file > new project` works?

Comment: does not work, it react not

Comment: try uninstall and reinstall again

Comment: What does the `Ctrl + Shift + N` shortcut does? Which Netbeans 8.2 did you download? *All*? *Java EE*?

Comment: Your problem is answered in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46476470/cant-create-project-on-netbeans-8-2

Answer (score 4):

It might have been caused by JDK 9. You could have changed the JDK 9 to previous version and it would have worked.

For that you would have to go to:
\NetBeans 8.2\etc

Then you can edit: netbeans.conf . Just change the directory for JDK from 9 to previous version if it is installed. (or install JDK 8 and then do the same process)

Answer (score 1):

I have uninstalled the NetBeans 8.2, which I downloaded it alone from NetBeans website, after that I have downloaded it as a complete package together with Java SDK from Java website, now it functions wonderful

Answer (score 1):

[Netbeans 8.2](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-3413139-esa.html) is bundled with Oracle JDK 8. Just download the installer for your platform and install it. I have tested the installer with Windows 10 and it works like a charm.