# Can't create project on Netbeans 8.2 with JDK 9.0.4

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to create a Java 9 project with Netbeans but netbeans IDE 8.2 is not working with "Java 9.0.4". Menu buttons doesn't response anything.

When I make some search [Can't create project on Netbeans 8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46476470/cant-create-project-on-netbeans-8-2)

Uninstalling jdk 9.0.4 offered as solution. Is there any way to create a Java 9 project with Netbeans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetBeans 8.2 does not support Java 9, but there is a beta version of NetBeans 9 available for download:

https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/incubator/netbeans/incubating-netbeans-java/incubating-9.0-beta/incubating-netbeans-java-9.0-beta-bin.zip

The download is a zip file which runs on all platforms. It supports all Java releases including JDK 9, and JDK 10. It is to be formally released later this month.

You can view and report bugs here:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues/NETBEANS-330?filter=allopenissues

Also note that you can run NetBeans 8.2 and NetBeans 9 beta concurrently.

See here for more information: https://netbeans.apache.org/

Another approach is to run the nightly dev build of NetBeans (http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/) which supports JDK 9 but not JDK 10. Hoever, this is a release from Oracle which is currently in the process of handing over NetBeans to Apache, and I doubt if there is much support if you have problems.