# I cannot create a new Java application in NetBeans 7

Tags: netbeans

I've just installed NetBeans 7.3.1.
I'm just trying to create a new Java application but whenever I go through the wizard it says "Project folder exists and is not empty" and won't go any further. This is a new project so the folder does not exist until NetBeans creates it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't create project on Netbeans 8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46476470/cant-create-project-on-netbeans-8-2)

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd suggest is to look for any anti-virus in your system that is not letting your NetBeans create any new Project.

**You can try** :

1 Disabling your anti-virus and try again.

2 Installing IDE in any other Drive except C Drive.

3 One more method but it is bit complex

- Step 1: See if you can create a new project in a folder that doesn't
  exist yet. Suppose the IDE does make this new folder for you, starts
  filling it with files, then stops unexpectedly and says that 'Project
  folder already exists, etc'.
- Step 2: Look inside the folder and try
  to locate the main class for your application (e.g.,

> C:\NetBeans_Projects\MyNiftyJavaApp\src\myniftyjavaapp\MyNiftyJavaApp.java)

- Step 3: If the main class file does exist but is totally empty (0
  bytes in length) it might mean that something prevents the IDE from
  filling it with automatically generated code (as happened to me
  because of the invalid main class template).

**Last thing you could do is upgrading your NetBeans version.**