# Can't create project on Netbeans 8.2 with JDK 10

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans, java-10

I am trying to create project on Ubuntu.It just can't do it. Doesn't give me an error or something, just this blank screen.

Help/About:

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.2 Patch 2
Java: 10.0.2; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.1
Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.1
System: Linux version 4.15.0-33-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)
User directory: /home/q/.netbeans/8.2
Cache directory: /home/q/.cache/netbeans/8.2
```

***My Installation Steps:***

**Step 1-** I have installed latest JDK from Oracle:[jdk-10.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk10-downloads-4416644.html)

**Step 2-** Extract all packages move file with

```
sudo mv jdk-10.0.2 /usr/lib/jvm
```

**Step 3-** Set environment variable as we do in Windows System Update your .bashrc file and add the following line

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-10.0.2
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

**Step 4-**

```
chmod a+x netbeans-8.2-linux.sh
```

**Step 5-**

```
./netbeans-8.2-linux.sh
```

**Step 6-** Change the JDK directory in the Netbeans installation

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-10.0.2
```

**Step 7-** Finish Installation

I have also looked at the following question. But I don't want to use JDK 8 which is an ancient version of JDK.
[Can't create project on Netbeans 8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46476470/cant-create-project-on-netbeans-8-2)

This problem has started when I have moved Wİndows 10 to Ubuntu LTS 18.04.

IDE Log(Too much long for stackoverflow):https://shrib.com/#0waz1WhsX_zc_.FCtjex

Comment: Update your post with any relevant messages from the NetBeans log. You can access that using **View > IDE Log**, but if you can't access it that way due to your problems, you can access it directly. See [NetBeans - where to find the IDE log?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50462124/2985643) for details on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for advice.

Comment: Your problem is due to NetBeans 8.2 not supporting JDK10. If you want to use NetBeans 8.2 then use JDK8 instead of JDK10. However, if you want to use JDK10 then [download and install Apache NetBeans 9.0](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html). Note that you can safely use NetBeans 8.2 and NetBeans 9.0 concurrently if you wish; there is no need to uninstall NB 8.2 to use NB 9.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NetBeans IDE 8.2 does not support JDK 10. Go to netbeans.apache.org and install the latest release of NetBeans instead.

Comment: How can I download the latest one from `netbeans.apache.org` ? it leads to a shell script on web.