# How to create Java project in Netbeans, without using Maven as default?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, windows-10, netbeans-11

I'm currently trying to create a basic Java project. The first option that appears is "Java with Maven", which I already used, but isn't giving me the "Create Main Class" option that I need.

I'm using Apache Netbeans IDE 11.0, running on Windows 10, x64.
I've given it a whole day, updating and installing the most recent JDK versions I found, and still I'm unable to make it work.

I've also read this answer, but it's not working:
[Can't create project on Netbeans 8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46476470/cant-create-project-on-netbeans-8-2#)

Here's an image of what I'm getting:

[image: ProjectWizrdOnNetBeans11]

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use "Java with Maven" and write the Main class yourself?

Comment: I actually did that, once I realized I was unable to fix it. But I'm still wondering why it doesn't work. Maybe it's because I didn't install it properly, or because I'm missing a certain package, or library.
I'll post an update once I'm able to fix it.

Comment: In the other hand: all real Java projects are built with Maven or Gradle.

Comment: @skomisa Ok, I simplified the situation more than necessary.  Let me phrase it differently: Today you need a very good reason to start a Java project without Maven or Gradle.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JFMeier. I'm definitely learning more than what I would've been able to do by my own.

Comment: I do not agree... newer versions have not space for beginners... It seems that netbeans became more autistic...! Although this is a feature of open source in general

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The project templates were revised in Apache NetBeans 11.0 to give Maven projects greater prominence. From an [Apache NetBeans blog post](https://blogs.apache.org/netbeans/entry/restructuring-of-project-templates-in):

> **Restructuring of Project Templates in Apache NetBeans**
>
> There's been lots of discussion in the Apache NetBeans community about
>   how best to express the fact that Apache Maven and Apache Gradle are
>   more modern choices to be aware of than Apache Ant, while at the same
>   time not implying that there's anything wrong with using Apache Ant.
>
> Here's what we seem to have reached consensus around, i.e., move all
>   Ant-based project templates into a separate Ant-specific folder, while
>   putting the other two build systems higher and therefore more
>   prominently in the list:

[image: new project templates]

> With the above, someone is less likely to simply go to the
>   no-longer-existing Java category and then end up with an Ant-based
>   project, without thinking about it. By default, the user of Apache
>   NetBeans is now encouraged to consider Apache Maven and Apache Gradle
>   first. **The old Ant-related categories are still there, so as not to
>   confuse anyone completely, just structured within a lower ranked "Java
>   with Ant" category.** The above also solves the discussion re "Java EE",
>   i.e., here the idea, from discussions, is to name the category "Java
>   Enterprise".
>
> At startup, all categories are closed, i.e., none is more prominent
>   initially than any other.
>
> An objection one could have is that, if you're a complete Java newbie,
>   you won't know what Maven, Gradle, or Ant are. Well, that has always
>   been the case and **NetBeans has artificially hidden that choice by
>   having a category simply named "Java", which then resulted in everyone
>   ending up with Ant-based projects.** To turn that around and have a
>   category simply named "Java" that results in Maven-based projects is
>   probably not right either, i.e., a careful balance needs to be struck.

So if you created a project using **File > New Project... > Java > Java Application** in earlier releases of NetBeans, you should use **File > New Project... > Java with Ant > Java Application** in NetBeans 11.0.

Notes:

- NetBeans Bug Report [NETBEANS-2040 Maven First in New Project Wizard](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2040) refers.
- Also see the discussion at the start of this YouTube video [The Rough Guide to Apache NetBeans 11.0](https://youtu.be/vCN_XvXQzzo).
- Other project wizard changes in NetBeans 11.0:

  - In NetBeans 11.0 I had to install the Gradle plugin (**Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins > Gradle**) in order to see **Java with Gradle** in the Project Wizard.
  - In earlier releases of NetBeans you created a Java Enterprise project using **File > New Project... > Java EE > ...**, but in NetBeans 11.0 this has changed to **File > New Project... > Java with Ant > Java Enterprise > ...**

Comment: Somehow netbeans 12.3 just rendered my ant project useless. run menu items are disabled. used to work before but now, when i select the folder it says to open the project right away. problem is, if i do, it makes it a maven project instead.

Comment: @chitgoks  Sound like a bug. Perhaps create a new SO question for that? You could also [report the issue to NetBeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/participate/report-issue.html).

Comment: had to change my source folder to src/main/java. no choice. the old project just had src/ and it worked before until 12.3