# Normal java category not found in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am new to using Netbeans and I need some help. I am trying to use outside libraries on my java project through Netbeans.

When I select file>new project, the new project window comes up where you can choose your category and project type. On my window, the only options are java with maven, java with Gradle, java with ant, html5/javascript, php, and samples. On all the youtube tutorials I see, everyone installs Netbeans, and right from the first startup, they will have a "java" option under categories. I don't have one for some reason and I can't find anything on the internet to help.

I need the basic java category because it is the one that allows you to download jar libraries which is what I need to do.

Note: I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling.
I also will go into the tools>plugins>installed. And it shows that the "Java SE" is installed and activated.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I do have the JDK properly installed and it is working. I can code in java with java maven and the other java categories just fine. Programs run and all. Just no basic java option. I have netbeans IDE 11.2 on mac

Comment: There is nothing for you to fix. Some wording for the **New Project...** wizard changed with NetBeans 11, and for a simple project use _"Java with Ant"_. In earlier releases you were actually also using "Java with Ant" but the wording didn't make it clear. See the accepted answer to [How to create Java project in Netbeans, without using Maven as default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56311186/2985643) for more details on why the changes were made. That question is a little different to yours, but the answer is still relevant for your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess starting In Netbeans 11 they don't list it as "Just Java" anymore, but you still can use the same one, it just listed as "Java with Ant" now.

As shown in the pic, this is how you Start a New Swing Based Java or the "Normal Java".

**How to start 'Normal' Java Swing Project in Netbeans 11**

[image: How to start 'Normal' Java Swing Project in Netbeans 11]

Comment: Oh okay I tried that and it worked! Thank you for your help