# why did Apache removed java web app feature from it's IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, netbeans-platform

I have been using an older version of NetBeans (8.2) to create web services and applications in my college. However, I recently discovered that the newer version of Apache NetBeans has switched to Maven. Despite asking around and searching online, I haven't found a clear answer on why ***java web*** feature was removed from older versions of Apache NetBeans and Maven was adopted for all future IDE updates.

[java web feature removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kEOd.png).

Can someone guide me on how to utilize the Maven feature in the newer version of Apache NetBeans for creating Java web applications? I would appreciate any step-by-step instructions or relevant resources to help me get started. Thank you in advance!

are older versions of IDE still used in Industry when we have the latest version of Apache Netbeans which has maven instead?

**Why did Apache remove the Java web app feature in its newer versions of IDE; Is there some problem with older versions of IDE using the Java web app feature?**
[java web feature removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kEOd.png).

Comment: I have Netbeans 16 and it has `Java with Ant/Java Web` under the (new project) categories, with `Web Application` as one of the project types.  I build a recent web application with it - can't remember how I got it to work :P

Comment: [1] The _"java web feature" has not been removed. Try **File > New Project... > Java with Ant > Java Web > Web Application**. [2] Your question is close enough to be a duplicate of [How to create Java project in Netbeans, without using Maven as default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56311186/2985643) The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56330546/2985643) explains why the changes were made to NetBeans. [3] Your need for guidance on using Maven is off topic here, but since you can still create web applications using the familiar approach that is probably no longer a concern anyway.

Comment: (For all who have helped me)--->@skomisa and @MadProgrammer . **Thank you sincerely for your tremendous assistance. As a newcomer to Java, I'm still navigating uncharted territory and encountering countless unknowns. Having a mentor like yourself has been an invaluable resource. I am genuinely grateful for the time and effort you invest in guiding newbies like me. Your support means a great deal to me.**